# NSURLConnection/NSURLRequest gzip support

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, gzip, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

Does anyone knows if NSURLConnection/NSURLRequest have support for gzip requests.

If does, can you provide more information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accept-Encoding: gzip on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333857/accept-encoding-gzip-on-ios)

Comment: @JoshCaswell, please check the date difference. It was asked 5 years after this question was posted.

Comment: [Duplicates don't always have to point in the direction of the later date](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/159251). I believe the answer at the other question is a bit more useful than those found here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044239/nsurlsession-download-and-do-not-decompress-gzip. `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` is automatically added to the request's header [NSURLSession].

Answer (score 68, accepted):

although it [does not seem to be documented](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlconnection), [there is evidence](http://www.google.com/search?q=NSURLConnection+gzip) that `NSURLConnection` *does* have transparent gzip support. meaning that if the server supports gzip encoding, and your request has an `Accept-Encoding` header containing `gzip`*, the server will send a gzipped response, which `NSURLConnection` will automatically decode.

* `NSURLRequest` might add that header by default. if not, you have to add it manually like so:

```
 [urlReq setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"]
```

Comment: 1. i think you need an NSMutableURLRequest to add a header 2. as of "iOS 3.2" as base sdk, the accept-encoding header containing deflate and gzip seems to be included automatically (apparently didn't used to be).

Comment: I've just done tests as well and saw that iPhone adds gzip and deflate by default. Does anyone know if it was always supported or since which version Apple has started including Accept-Encoding by default?

Comment: What about gzip encoding requests sent to the server? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204066/how-to-gzip-an-nsurlconnection-request

Comment: After receiving the data, do I have to unzip the received data?

Comment: @Satyamsvv _[...]... the server will send a gzipped response, which NSURLConnection **will automatically decode**._

Comment: How can I verify if this is taking affect?

Comment: How to get Response Data before compression? What layer does this decompression happen ？CFNetwork?

Comment: @BeyondChao Do you mean "response data before **_de_**compression"?

Answer (score 3):

`NSURLRequest` decodes gzip to `NSData`; such as the Server response contain `"Content-Encoding" = gzip`; the `NSData` will decode.
If you don't want to automatically decode it, add the code below. This is a private API.

```
//import CFNetwork.framework
extern CFStringRef kCFURLRequestDoNotDecodeData;
typedef const struct _CFURLRequest* CFURLRequestRef;
extern void _CFURLRequestSetProtocolProperty(CFURLRequestRef,CFStringRef,CFTypeRef);

//NSURLRequest init ...
//...
CFURLRequestRef requestRef = (CFURLRequestRef)[request performSelector:@selector(_CFURLRequest)];
_CFURLRequestSetProtocolProperty(requestRef,kCFURLRequestDoNotDecodeData,kCFBooleanTrue);
```

Comment: I filed a request at bugreport.apple.com that this or an equivalent API be made public. http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4931101243998208

Comment: Did this ever get solved? I need a way to download a stream without it being automatically unzipped.

Comment: @casolorz This bug has fixed on recent iOS version，it work well on iOS8 and later

Comment: @casolorz can you elaborate? the "bug" is here described as a missing API - so what API fills the gap? how do you control an NSURLSession, or the request/response to use gzip (or not)? how do you instruct the NSURLSession to leave the response encoded, and hand it to you as is?

Comment: @MottiShneor think you meant to ask someone else that?