# How to gzip an NSURLConnection request?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gzip, nsurlconnection

Apparently, [`NSURLConnection` automatically decodes gzipped responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682483/nsurlconnection-nsurlrequest-gzip-support/2683986#2683986). But, can it gzip encode its requests? If so, how? Or, does it do this automatically too?

Answer (score 5):

An HTTP request body cannot be gzipped at the protocol level, as there is no way for the client to know whether the server supports that or not; it works for the server response because the client indicates in the request whether a gzipped response body can be accepted. (It could be done in the future something like how `Expect: 100-continue` works, but that's not the situation we're faced with today).

At the application level, you certainly could gzip the request body. But that would be outside the realm of NSURLConnection.

Comment: Interesting. Can you show an example of how to gzip a request to be sent with `NSURLConnection`? Or, would I have to use another library, like [ASIHTTP, that supports gzip compression of request bodies for POST & PUT](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#using_gzip_to_compress_request_bodies)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually all for using NSURLRequests over ASIHTTPRequests, but ASI does handle this case. HTTP request compression isn't something you can use all the time safely. You can't detect whether a server will handle this correctly on a route. Even if you get Apache setup to handle this correctly it will fail when making requests on different modules since they might not handle it correctly.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#using_gzip_to_compress_request_bodies