# Is iOS removing the Content-MD5 HTTP header?

Tags: ios

I use a web application that's returning a Content-MD5 header but in my iOS app, I cannot retrieve that header using `[NSHTTPURLResponse allHeaderFields]` (whereas I can see it when I use cURL).

Does anyone know if iOS is deliberately removing that header?

Comment: did you mean `NSHTTPURLResponse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured out what's happened.

Our SaaS provider has activated gzip by default on non-production instances. As mentioned in some other threads, [NSURLConnection supports gzip compression transparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682483/nsurlconnection-nsurlrequest-gzip-support) and will automatically send the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` HTTP header. When the response is received, `NSURLConnection` decompresses the content and removes the Content-Md5 header (because the Content-MD5 is a hash of the compressed data), which is why I'm not seeing it in the list of received headers.