# Accept-Encoding: gzip on iOS

Tags: ios, http-compression

**Q1** With the iOS App kit, can I expect that [`Accept-Encoding: gzip`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) will be used automatically, or do I need to explicitly ask for it to be used by setting this in the URL request somewhere?

I'm currently using the call `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url]`, although I am likely to change over to specifically setting up an NSURLSession – is this likely to automatically request gzip encoding?

**Q2** Also, if it *is* used and the server obliges with gzip-ed content, am I correct that the client side will automatically decode the compressed content transparently so that I don't need to?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's all automatic, though I'm not immediately able to find an authoritative reference. You can prove it empirically using a proxy.

The best I can find so far: the [iOS 7.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.1/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013935) mention in passing that...

> A compatibility behavior has been added to address an issue where some
>   web servers would send the wrong Content-Length value for
>   “Content-Encoding: gzip” content. Previously, NSURLConnection and
>   NSURLSession would send a “network connection was lost” /
>   NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost (-1005) error in this situation.
>
> The compatibility behavior applies only if the Content-Length value
>   exactly matches the expanded gzip’d content. It won’t apply for “off
>   by 1” or similar miscounting.

i.e. `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLSession` include code to handle gzip content, and definitely did so prior to 7.1 (as per the reference to "previously"). Anecdotally, they appear to have done so since time immemorial but in any case 7.0+ is about 98% of the app-downloading market now.

Comment: follow up of the answer above read [URL Loading System](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA)

Comment: Hi @tommy, thanks – I've done a slight edit to the question to make clear that there are two parts to the question. I think you've given an answer to Q2, but not to Q1?

Comment: I've found a proper source for Q2 but the answer is 'yes' to both from experience. I'll keep hunting.

Comment: Since you're the only one with concrete answer to these questions - I'll ask you one more: Will this also happen automatically also for upload requests? Suppose my body of a POST request is a huge ugly JSON - can I trust NSURLSession to deflate it before sending? Should I somehow tell it to do that? use specific extra headers? how to go about it?