# Do you need to send "Accept-Encoding: gzip" header for NSURLRequest(s)?

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest

Do we need to manually send this header in Objective-C/Swift in order to get GZipped content back from the server, or will it always send it since iOS accepts it seamlessly?

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682483/nsurlconnection-nsurlrequest-gzip-support)