# NSURLSession - download and do *not* decompress gzip?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I'm using `NSURLSession`'s `dataTaskWithRequest` to download a file. It's gzipped, and it is automatically decompressed. However, I don't want it to be - I want the gzipped source. Is there any way to disable decompression?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I suspect that the server sending the data with a different MIME type would solve it.  You might also be able to solve it by setting the "Content-Encoding" header to something other than "gzip" in the request.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, I ended up just having to work around the issue unfortunately.

Comment: @Alastair, can you share your hack? Did you actually use `DataTask` or `DownloadTask`?

Answer (score 12):

`NSURLSession` automatically inserts this value to your request's header:

```
"Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5"
```

which causes the downloaded data to be automatically decoded. 
So I think you should start by replacing the value of "Accept-Encoding" with something else.

Comment: Unfortunately taking away `Accept-Encoding: gzip` means most servers will send back an uncompressed response, which I don't want!

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the Content-Type, if the Content-Type says it's text/html, it doesn't matter whether it's zipped or not, Task will call completion with text/html bytes.

Anyhow, if you have the wrong Content-Type, and still want this, you can instance NSURLDownload (it's the legacy url loading system), implement and set a delegate (NSURLDownloadDelegate), and in your delegate implement this:

```
- (BOOL)download:(NSURLDownload *)download 
shouldDecodeSourceDataOfMIMEType:(NSString *)encodingType {
   return NO;
}
```

There's no way to do it with URLSession AFAIK, except of course implementing your own protocol, but that might be too much.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will reslove:

```
- (BOOL)download:(NSURLDownload *)download shouldDecodeSourceDataOfMIMEType:(NSString *)encodingType;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).